# Percentage of contribution using average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions, average, percentages

I want to calculate how much an individual employee in a Business Unit (BU) of a company contributed to the overall total expense (salary) of that BU.

I have the company wide calculated Average Salary for each experience levels (such as associate, manager). I also have the total expense of any given BU, along with employee headcount, and their individual experience levels.

Suppose the BU total salary and the count of employees of that BU is as follows:

| Company | ABC Inc. |
| --- | --- |
| Average Salary of associate | 10 |
| Average Salary of manager | 40 |

| BU | HR |
| --- | --- |
| Total BU Expense | 80 |
| No of Employees in BU | 4 |
| Headcount of associates | 2 |
| Headcount of manager | 2 |

It is obvious that the company wide average cannot be substituted directly as it would total to 100 instead of 80:

`(2 associates * 10)+(2 managers * 40) = 100`

So, I want to calculate how much % did each employee contribute to this BU total of 80.

Is there a way to calculate the individual's contribution percentages to the BU cost?

*Freehand calculation:*
Associate average in this specific BU:
`6.25% of 80 = 5`
Manager Average in this specific BU:
`43.75% of 80 = 35`

`(2 associates * 5)+(2 managers * 35) = 80`

I think this is closely related to the question: [Percentage of contribution to the average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795992/percentage-of-contribution-to-the-average)

Comment: You could get somewhere if you're able to assume some constant ratio of manager to associate pay across business units. Overall in this company, the average manager gets paid 4x as much as the average associate. Is that true in this BU as well? Your calculation suggests that managers make 7x as much as associates in this BU. As far as I can tell, you've basically input that 7x factor as a given and solved for the appropriate salaries given the total, but I don't see why you should assume a higher or lower pay disparity.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie thanks. I am starting to understand the need for a ratio to become constant. The averages change every month, but stays constant for any given month. Assuming managers make 4x compared to associate, how would I proceed? My calculation (turns out to be 7x which is wrong) was a sample one just to showcase what kind of percentage or value I am trying to get. Also, will the average salary value be of any use in the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the number of associates, number of managers, and total cost, and an additional assumption of the pay disparity between managers and associates, you can solve for the average pay of managers/associates in this business unit.

$A$ = # of associates

$M$ = # of managers

$F$ = pay disparity factor (how many times the associates pay is the manager's pay)

$T$ = total cost

$X$ = average salary of one associate

$T = AX + MFX$

$X = T/(A+MF)$

Without an estimate of the pay disparity factor, you can't do much - the total cost will be divided differently if managers make the same amount as associates, or much more, or much less.